# Segmentation Fault While Checking Pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program that reads a dictionary file (text file, one word per line), and inserts it into a structure consisting of a "linked list" of arrays, where the word is recursively forwarded to the [first letter - 'a'] entry of an array (which is another array, that processes the next letter). When the whole word is "consumed", it inserts the word (unchanged) in a regular linked list of words. The program successfully processes first 15 words, but at 16-th it throws segmentation fault.

It looks like the segmentation fault occurs in add() method in the following snippet:

```
struct LinkedList * new = (struct LinkedList *) calloc(1,
                                       sizeof(struct LinkedList));
            if (!new) {
                perror("Not enough memory!"); // Error here
                exit(2);
            }
```

(Hopefully) Relevant code:

```
void addList (struct LinkedList * list, char * word) {
    if (!list->next)
    {
        struct LinkedList * new = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
        if (!new) {
            perror("Not enough memory!");
            exit(2);
        }

        char * new_word = malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
        if (!new_word) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!");
            exit(2);
        }


        new->next = 0;
        strcpy(new_word, word);
        new->word = new_word;
        list->next = new;
    }
    else
    {
        addList(list->next, word);
    }
}


void add(struct HashTree * root, char * word, char * word_sorted, int length) {

    if (length == 0)                                     // Found the correct place
    {

        if (!root->words)                                // If words are not allocated
        {
            // Create list node
            struct LinkedList * new = calloc(1, sizeof(struct LinkedList));
            if (!new) {
                perror("Not enough memory!");
                exit(2);
            }

            char * new_word = malloc(strlen(word) * sizeof(char));
            if (!new_word) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory!");
                exit(2);
            }

            new->next = 0;

            strcpy(new_word, word);

            new->word = new_word;
            root->words = new;
        }   

        else                                            // Add to the Linked List
        {
            addList(root->words, word);
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        // printf("Length_add = %d\n", length);
        if (!root->next)                                 // If the array was not allocated yet
        {

            struct HashTree * new = malloc(27 * sizeof(struct HashTree *));
            if (!new) {
                perror("Not enough memory!");
                exit(2);
            }


            root->next = new;
        }


        add(&(root->next[ word_sorted[0] - 'a' ]), 
            word, (char *) (word_sorted +1), (length-1));  // Use the next letter.

    }


}
```

To save the space, [Here is the link to the full code.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiQ2ZiYVlQUDBGWFk/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the output of gdb core and backtrace:

```
    Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 

100 perror("Not enough memory!");
```

[Full GDB output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiZjRVN0lKNmR6S2s/view?usp=sharing)

I implemented a similar algorithm in Java before, and the algorithm seems to be correct. I am pretty new to C, and don't understand what might be wrong. I would really appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Deleted sort, clean and cleanWords methods (they does not greatly affect the adding of the word to the structure). Segmentation occurred while processing the second word, line 125:

```
perror("Dictionary file not found!");
```

[Link to code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiZXhpYk50dmhIelU/view?usp=sharing)   -
[Link to sample dictionary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiXzEzUkk2UkRWczA/view?usp=sharing)

[Valgrind output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiSUo2LWNhcmRPdWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Off-topic: try to loose the Java-style. Don't check, just do the things that are needed. (and can be done) And: pointers-to-pointers help a lot. In the end. (and will reduce your code size to one third, at least)

Comment: TL;DR. Use a debugger, cut down to a [mcve]. Use `const` where approvriate. Also do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @wildplasser Should I omit checking for null in pointers? I don't know how to make it less Java-style. If you could give an example, I might understand it better. Thanks.

Comment: @Olaf I tried to cut it down in size, but every time it changes the location of the segmentation fault.

Comment: Why does that hinder stripping down the code? And what does that tell you? Oh, and while not a reserved word in C, `new` should not be use nevertheless (this is more a style recommendation).

Comment: This isn't the cause of your problem, but in C it has not been good practice to cast the return of malloc, realloc or calloc for many years now.

Comment: @PavlikPetrovich - for best results, your question should include the input data you're using.

Comment: You have **two** declarations of `i` variable in a nested `for loops`

Comment: @PavlikPetrovich I'm also wondering how that code compiles. You need to disambiguate those two first to simplify your problems. Also, what's wrong with `strlen`? Why don't you just use it?

Comment: @mr5 Just checked, it does not complain (about i), it just does not matter. With strlen it's my mistake - I thought it will return the size of allocated array. And yes, the code compiles without errors.

Comment: Time to get [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) on the job if at all possible.  If your problem moves as you remove code, you almost certainly are mismanaging dynamically allocated memory, and there's a decent chance `valgrind` will tell you where.  It probably won't be this function that's causing the trouble.  Crashing in `perror()` when you pass a literal string to it strongly hints at serious memory corruption.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I added a link to the output of Valgrind. The problem is, I don't have any experience with it, and Valgrind shows too many errors. It is hard to understand them are my errors.

Comment: Post relevant code here.

Comment: The first two entries are definitely your problem (as opposed to anyone else's).  You're using unitialized data; don't.  You're copying beyond the end of your allocated space; don't do that either.  Go through, fixing each one in turn.  Start at the top and work your way down. _[…later…]_ all the problems look like mismanaged memory — uninitialized variables, not allocating enough memory (do you account for the trailing null byte), or accessing wild pointers. Use compiler warnings: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Thank you. A question - am  I doing something wrong checking if the pointer exists by using `if (!root->next)` ? It looks like Valgrind does not like this line.

Comment: If you're sure `root` is a non-null pointer, then checking that `root->next` is non-null is often written that way, though I personally prefer `if (root->next != 0)` or `if (root->next != NULL)`.  If you don't know that `root` is not null, it is dangerous to dereference it — `if (root != 0 && root->next != 0)` is safe.  If root points somewhere indeterminate — you didn't initialize it, either to null or to some valid value, `valgrind` will justifiably complain.

Comment: I believe Java initializes variables by default.  C most definitely does not.  If you translate an algorithm from Java to C, you have to ensure that variables are properly initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the main `else` clause of `add()`, you allocate some memory, but don't initialize it.  You then use the uninitialized memory in the next recursive call to `add()`.  At minimum, use `calloc()` in place of `malloc()` there.  You're also allocating only enough space for 27 pointers to your structures, but you're using it as though you allocated 27 structures.

Wrong:

```
struct HashTree * new = malloc(27 * sizeof(struct HashTree *));
```

Right:

```
struct HashTree *new = calloc(27, sizeof(struct HashTree));
```

Or:

```
struct HashTree *new = calloc(27, sizeof(*new));
```

Also, in both `addList()` and `add()`, you are not allocating enough space for the string; you forgot the trailing null.

Wrong:

```
char *new_word = (char *) malloc(length * sizeof(char));
```

Right:

```
char *new_word = (char *) malloc(length + 1);
```

I don't use C++ keywords in my C code, so I'd use `new_hash` or thereabouts instead of just `new`.  Many would castigate you for the casts on the allocations.

With those changes, the code ran to completion for me.  It leaked like fury, but that was totally expected.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Leffler. It worked for me as well. as to memory leakage, I will continue to work on it.

Comment: AFAICR, there are no calls to `free()` in the code you posted, so the leak is not surprising.  What's the 27th entry in the trie-like structure used for?  The alphabet I use has just 26 letters, so I fear you are wasting some space there.

Comment: I have two separate methods for this, I think you went to the link with minimal code. [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8dXBGoXZiNiQ2ZiYVlQUDBGWFk/view?usp=sharing) is the one with actual code. Also, the file contains '\n' (Unix-style) newlines as separators, and 27-th is for " ' " character.

Comment: Yes, I only looked at the MCVE-ish code.  You can deal with the bigger code base to suit yourself.  I don't see any special handling for `'` in the MCVE-style code, which could be a problem (probably one I circumvented by largely accidentally switching to the local dictionary, and that contains no apostrophes).

Comment: I deal with it by replacing `'` with `'z' + 1` so it appears to be `{` (in sort function). Probably not the best way to do it, but it appears to be Ok for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

for errors like this the problem is almost always an issue with `fopen`. If I am right you may have forgotten to add the extension to a file or perhaps it is an issue with the file-paths you are using.

**My advice:**

use ctrl+f to locate all instances of `fopen` then verify that they reference the correct file.

**EDIT**
pay special attention to line 184. I suspect that `"/usr/share/dict/words"` should be `"/usr/share/dict/words.txt"`

**EDIT 2:**

instead of (line 200):

```
while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), dict) != NULL) {
```

try [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/):

```
while(!feof(dict)) {
    fscanf(dict, "%*[^']", MAX_WORD_LENGTH, word);
```

**EDIT**

Thank you @JonathanLeffler I would still recommend [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

```
int fscanf( FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ... );
```

If you use it right, `fscanf` can be very useful when reading formatted data.

```
fscanf(dict, "%*s", MAX_WORD_LENGTH, word);
fscanf(dict, "'", MAX_WORD_LENGTH, word);//get rid of the delimiter
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Although, the file path is correct - the program successfully reads (and processes) a few lines of this file. I am suspecting the problem is with pointers or allocation - but I have no idea where.

Comment: See [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong) for why you should not condition your loop as shown in this answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler interesting, I have never seen that before

Comment: You'd get away with it if you also (redundantly) tested the return value from `fscanf()` and broke the loop when it detected EOF.  As written, you process the last line twice, which is often not a good idea.  Plus you need to read the newlines somehow with `fscanf()` — there are a bag'o'worms associated with that, too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler look at the dict file she put up. It is a single line delimited by `'`

Comment: @chrisgotter: I didn't run into any problems with it when I downloaded it (either originally or when I checked again just now, since I'd cleaned up).  I saved it as `dict` and from `wc dict`, the output was `32      33     201 dict`.  I used that mostly when testing; I futzed the code to read stdin instead of `/usr/share/words/dict`.  When it was working, I used the original code verbatim except for the changes above, and it worked with the 235k+ words, allocating about 250 MiB in total, in just over 1M allocations.

Comment: ohh, it has unix line breaks. That makes way more sense. That'll teach me to use Notepad. :p